# JPA transactions: select right after commit?

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, ejb

I am using JBoss EAP 6.1.0 with EJB/JPA. I have a User object with several Groups he belongs to and I'm trying to create this in the database using a three step method:

1. Save the user
2. Save the groups he belongs to
3. Query the database and return that new user

My problem is that step (3) always returns back null because the commit hasn't happened yet.  Adding an `em.flush()` between step 2 and 3 does not help.  I'm avoiding any @CASCADE annotations with the Groups so saving just the User and having Groups cascade is not an option.  Here is sample code:

```
@Stateless
public class RegistrationService {

   @EJB
   UserDao userDao;

   public User registerNewUser(User user, List<Group> groups) {
       userDao.saveNewUser(user);
       userDao.saveNewGroupsToUser(user, groups);
       return userDao.findUser(user);
   }
}
```

And here is a simplified UserDao:

```
@Stateless
public class UserDao {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void saveNewUser(User user) {
    em.persist(user);
  }

  public void saveNewGroupsToUser(User user, List<Group> groups) {
    for (Group group : groups) {
       GroupToUser groupToUser = new GroupToUser(user, group);
       em.persist(groupToUser);
    }

  public User findUser(User user) {
    return em.createQuery("from User where user = :userId")
       .setParameter("userId",user.getUserId())
       .getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

What I have found is that if I annotate the `findUser(User)` method with a `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` it works as expected.  Why is this though?  I thought `registerNewUser()` created one big transaction, and then findUser() would create a nested transaction which shouldn't know about the saving yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `findUser()` method. Since container managed transactions (CMT) do not allow nested transactions, this seems to flush the previous SQL update/insert statements allowing the select to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add em.flush() after step 1 (after save the user) as it will execute the SQL for save new user.

Second thing, from code it seems that container managed transaction are used. CMT don''t allow nested transaction. So basically adding REUIRED_NEW attribute might force to flush the previous save SQL queries. One way to confirm this is to log SQL queries

Comment: The em.flush() after saving seems to have no effect, I'm still getting back null. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I think I will just stick with the `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `findUser()` method since that does the trick.  Since I am using CMT this might be the best I can get.